# ui:with, style not showing up

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to share a CSS across multiple widgets using .

I can see that css class name are obfuscated but the class definition 
is not showing up when I inspect the element in firefox / chrome. 
Here're my codes.  Can anyone suggest what am I missing?  Thanks.

Style.css

```
.nameSpan {  color: #3E6D8E; background-color: #E0EAF1;}
```

Resources.java

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle { 
  @Source("Style.css") 
  Style style(); 
  public interface Style extends CssResource { 
    String nameSpan(); 
  } 
}
```

uibinder.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' 
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'> 
  <ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/> 
  <g:HTMLPanel> 
      <div> 
        Well hello there 
        <g:InlineLabel ui:field='nameSpan' styleName="res.style.nameSpan">kevin</g:InlineLabel>
      </div> 
  </g:HTMLPanel> 
</ui:UiBinder>
```

uibinder.class

```
public class uibinder extends Composite { 
        private static uibinderUiBinder uiBinder =     GWT.create(uibinderUiBinder.class); 
        interface uibinderUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, uibinder> {} 
        @UiField(provided = true)  final Resources res;  // the style doesn't show no matter provided=true is declared or not. 
        public uibinder(Resources res) { 
                res = GWT.create(Resources.class); 
                initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)); 
        }
```

Comment: And don't forget to call: `res.style().ensureInjected();`

Comment: Yes, it's the solution!!!  Thanks.  You should put it as the answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `res.style().ensureInjected()`

Comment: Hilbrand has already mentioned that.  But yes, it's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the style (`styleName` attribute) somewhere. For example:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'> 
    <ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/> 
    <g:HTMLPanel> 
        <div> 
            Well hello there 
            <g:InlineLabel ui:field='nameSpan' styleName="{res.nameSpan}">kevin</g:InlineLabel>
        </div> 
    </g:HTMLPanel> 
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The attribute `ui:field` you've declared does not set the css style. It defines the attribute that is to be filled in in your `uibinder` class. See the [GWT doc](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) for some guidance.

Comment: In fact, I did add the styleName but the style is not showing.  I have edited the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: In that case, you may want to check that the curly braces in z00bs's code snippet exist in your code too.